# Patch version of ASP Core (preview 4) with AppVeyor

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, appveyor

How to patch Asp.Net Core project (csproj) in order to build versioned binaries with AppVeyor?
Is there a way to apply versioning separately for AssemblyVersion and FileVersion?

AppVeyor has predefined step to patch AssemblyInfo.cs file, but it isn't included into project and functionality of AssemblyInfo moved to csproj file, therefore it's not clear how to deal with versioning.

Appreciate you help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As .NET Core .csproj is a regular XML you can use PowerShell script to update the version information in it. For example, you might have the following `MyProject\MyProject.csproj`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.0</TargetFramework>
    <Version>1.2.3.4</Version>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
    <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App" Version="1.0.1" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Then on AppVeyor the script patching `<Version>` would be the following:

```
$xmlPath = "$env:appveyor_build_folder\MyProject\MyProject.csproj"
$xml = [xml](get-content $xmlPath)
$propertyGroup = $xml.Project.PropertyGroup | Where { $_.Version}
$propertyGroup.Version = $env:appveyor_build_version
$xml.Save($xmlPath)
```

Comment: Thanks, Feodor this solution helped!

Comment: Will this be implemented in AppVeyor?

Comment: Yes, we have an issue for that: https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/1404